# Doxygen: Any way to limit/ignore specific doxygen warnings such as same name warnings, image warnings, ect. are not shown in the output?

Tags: doxygen

Using Doxygen and running the Doxyfile, the warnings output may come out to a terminal or a file. I am trying to ignore/suppress/limit certain warnings in this output since my repository is so big.

Examples of warnings I do not want in the output:

- supplied as the second argument in the \file statement matches the following input files: ""
- more #endifs than @ifs in ""
- \ref warnings in ""

Most likely there will be more that I do not want showing up so a general way to do things would be great.

I understand this isn't too hard in one file, but I would like to suppress them in every file that I have.

I tried modifying the Doxyfile but haven't found a way to limit certain warnings from showing up.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? The warnings signal your documentation and for correct documentation they should all be solved. The only way of manipulating the number of warnings is by means of setting the different options in the Doxyfile (maybe setting EXTRACT_ALL might help you in this case but it might also show thing you don't want to show in the documentation or filter to many warnings. Another way would be to post process the WARN_LOGFILE after doxygen has finished (but this is a task outside of doxygen).